# fullpath php not displaying path on website

Tags: php, .htaccess, github, github-pages, .htpasswd

I'm trying to [set up .htaccess on my website](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htaccess-authentication/)  (hosted by GitHub, and on a custom domain), and I can't seem to find the full path to my .htpasswd file, therefore the files aren't working. I've followed [this](http://www.htaccesstools.com/articles/full-path-to-file-using-php/) tutorial on how to find the full path, but whenever I try to open the .php script, it either shows the contents of the file in plain text, or downloads the script. It doesn't actually tell me the path to the .htpasswd file.

Is there another way of finding the full path, or am I doing it correctly, but there's a problem on GitHub's side... maybe it doesn't support PHP scripts?

I'd be happy to provide a link to the php file, and the .htaccess and .htpasswd files, if that would help.

PS: Tried doing it on Google Chrome (Latest) and Internet Explorer (The one that came with Win10). None managed to do it properly.

Thanks.

Comment: _(The one that came with Win10)_ - Edge?

Comment: Nope, the internet explorer that came with Win10. Edge is a bit too... underdeveloped for my liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github won't provide the same functionalities as a common host. It won't execute your PHP. It will just render your HTML.

Comment: Ah, was thinking that was the case. Ah, well. Thanks.